# Syntax error in FROM clause in OleDbCommand

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

When I Using this command to insert data, it's totally working..

```
using (con = new OleDbConnection(@"PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + @"DATA SOURCE=C:\Users\ABDUL MALEK\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite1\App_Data\Database.mdb"))
{
    cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into Customer(Customer_Phone,Customer_Name) VALUES('"+tb_CustNum.Text+"','"+tb_CustName.Text+"')";
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Label1.Visible= true;
}
```

But, after I add or replace this command, "Syntax error in FROM clause" shows up..

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Transaction(Product_Code,Date,Quantity,Total,Customer_Phone) values('" + ddl_PizzaCode.SelectedItem + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy") + "','" + tb_Quan.Text + "','" + Lb_Price.Text + "','" + tb_CustNum.Text + "')";
```

This is full code-behind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    OleDbConnection con;
    OleDbCommand cmd;

    int Quan;
    double TotalPrice;
    //int i = 0;
    string Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Lb_Date.Text = Date;
    }

    protected void bt_Calc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Quan = Convert.ToInt32(tb_Quan.Text);
        TotalPrice = Convert.ToDouble(Lb_Price.Text) * Quan;
        Lb_TotalPrice.Text = TotalPrice.ToString();
    }

    protected void ddl_PizzaCode_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string strquery = "SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ID = " + ddl_PizzaCode.SelectedValue;
        using (con = new OleDbConnection(@"PROVIDER= Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + @"DATA SOURCE =C:\Users\ABDUL MALEK\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite1\App_Data\Database.mdb"))
        {
            using (cmd = new OleDbCommand(strquery, con))
            {
                OleDbDataAdapter Da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                Da.Fill(dt);
            }
            Lb_PizzaName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Product_Name"].ToString();
            Lb_Price.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Price_per_Unit"].ToString();
        }
    }

    protected void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (con = new OleDbConnection(@"PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + @"DATA SOURCE=C:\Users\ABDUL MALEK\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite1\App_Data\Database.mdb"))
        {
            cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into Transaction(Product_Code,Date,Quantity,Total,Customer_Phone) values('" + ddl_PizzaCode.SelectedItem + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy") + "','" + tb_Quan.Text + "','" + Lb_Price.Text + "','" + tb_CustNum.Text + "')";
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into Customer(Customer_Phone,Customer_Name) VALUES('"+tb_CustNum.Text+"','"+tb_CustName.Text+"')";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Label1.Visible= true;
        }
        BindUserDetails();
    }
    protected void BindUserDetails()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
        string strquery = "SELECT * FROM Customer";
        string strquery2 = "SELECT * FROM Transaction";
        using (con = new OleDbConnection(@"PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + @"DATA SOURCE=C:\Users\ABDUL MALEK\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite1\App_Data\Database.mdb"))
        {
            using (cmd = new OleDbCommand(strquery, con))
            {
                OleDbDataAdapter Da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                Da.Fill(ds);
            }
            using (cmd = new OleDbCommand(strquery2, con))
            {
                OleDbDataAdapter Da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                Da.Fill(ds2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `VALUES('"+tb_CustNum.Text+"','"+tb_CustName.Text+"')"` Sql Injection !!!!!

Comment: You realize that your second `cmd.CommandText` overwrites the first one, right? If you want two INSERT commands in one command, you need to concatenate them with a semicolon. Also, please provide the full stack trace from the error.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't know how to concatenate them with a semicolon.. can you give me some example please?

Answer (score 0):

The word `DATE` is a keyword in SQL Server, and thus needs to be in square brackets when you are using it as a field name in C#. This line should work:

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Transaction(Product_Code, [Date], Quantity, Total, Customer_Phone) values('" + ddl_PizzaCode.SelectedItem + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy") + "','" + tb_Quan.Text + "','" + Lb_Price.Text + "','" + tb_CustNum.Text + "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

have you ever heard of SQL-Injection.... you are WIDE OPEN to exposure.

ALL your queries should have data cleaned and parameterized.  Never concatenate what you can't control from the web.

Using parameters in your commands basically means using the proper character identifier indicating a parameter.  In SQL and Access, you should be good with the "@" sign.  Other databases use different parameters.  VFP uses "?" as a place-holder, SAP Advantage Database uses ":".

Change your commands (all of them select, insert, update, delete) to something like..

```
 cmd.CommandText = 
@"insert into Customer
      ( Customer_Phone, Customer_Name ) 
   VALUES
      ( @parmCustomerPhone, @parmCustomerName)";

 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@parmCustomerPhone", tb_CustNum.Text );
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@parmCustomerName", tb_CustName.Text );
```

Then you should be good.  Concatenation can fail if someone puts in a quote ' as part of a name, such as "O'Mally".  The quote would mis-balance your quotes and cause failure.

If your columns are of numeric or date data types, make sure the parameter you are sending is of that type via the AddWithValue() call.

Additionally, for clarification, I am explicitly calling the values in the insert statement as "@parmSomething" so you know it is the parameter value, not the actual column name and avoiding confusion... especially as a beginner for web and querying.

Finally as noted by other.  Be careful about reserved words such as date, time, and other sql clauses. These should be qualified or wrapped in brackets such as [Date] or `Date`

As for your multiple insert statements, SQL typically uses a semi-colon to identify the end of one statement and allow there to be multiple in a single call such as

```
cmd.CommandText = 
@"insert into Transaction 
   ( Product_Code,
     [Date],
     Quantity,
     Total,
     Customer_Phone ) 
   values
   ( @parmPizza,
     @parmNow,
     @parmQty,
     @parmPrice,
     @parmPhone );

insert into Customer
   ( Customer_Phone,
     Customer_Name ) 
   VALUES
   ( @parmCustPhone,
     @parmCustName ) ";

// NOW, add all the parameters...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@eachParmAbove", respectiveTextDateNumericValue );
...
...
...
```

THEN execute it.  Hopefully the readability of these samples helps you too.